# SQL Server complaining about triggers returning result sets?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Ok so I made an application that was built to run using someone else's SQL Sever database, which is already in production. It's basically a small tool to go through and insert missing data where needed. I get the following error:

"A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was active."

What does this mean exactly and why am I getting it?

I'm probably not going to be able to change table definitions or mess with server configuration. I do a few selects to find where the data is missing and then I insert new records where needed. Is there any way to design a query to get around this?

Comment: Do you have any triggers that return resultsets? Can you add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to all triggers?

Comment: I wanted to maybe change my queries if possible but if altering the triggers is the only possible way then I could look at that. My SQL knowledge is not exactly elite, and the servers are doing serious business so I'm being careful not to do anything that could have repercussions.

Comment: Well, to be fair, whoever created these triggers and didn't realise what problems they would cause was hardly "elite" either.

Comment: Here's the thing though, the software already running on the server seems to be able to insert into those tables just fine. Information is getting in there so there has to be a way...