# what is the meaning of A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am getting this exception:

> A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF while another outstanding result set was activ

I want to know what is the meaning of that, with an example and how to avoid it (without `SET NOCOUNT ON` - as i need to know number of rows affected).

Here more explanation of what I am doing?

Let us say I have a table in my SQL Server DB with the name **AccNodesBal** and I have 3 triggers on that table:

- `FOR UPDATE`
- `INSERT`
- `DELETE`

I am using ADO.net as data layer. As you know, `FOR UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by **both**

- the insert or update operation
- **and** the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers.

For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

In my application (code) I am using `ExcecuteNonQuery` and get the number of rows affected in an `int` variable and validate that it's **2** to ensure that the trigger is fired and everything is logged.

But I am getting this error:

```
A trigger returned a resultset and/or was running with SET NOCOUNT OFF
while another outstanding result set was active.
```

After searching I have found that I have to use `SET NOCOUNT ON` keyword in my triggers. Unfortunately this will not work with my application, as the trigger will not now return any values of affected rows. Does anyone know another approach to get the number of rows affected from updates statement and trigger without using `SET NOCOUNT ON`?

Here is my code

```
int recCount = adpt.cmdMovementUpdate(
      amtType == EFG.Acc.AccNodeService.Contracts.Entities.AmountType.Debit ? 0 : Amount, 
      amtType == EFG.Acc.AccNodeService.Contracts.Entities.AmountType.Debit ? Amount : 0, 
      NodeID, PeriodID, Convert.ToInt16(CurrCode), Convert.ToByte(BalCurrType));
```

where `adpt` the **TableAdapter** contains my sql **Update** command query and it's implemented in a WCF service, which is consumed by a webservice, and the application consume this webservice.

After searching i see that it is recommended to use `SET NOCOUNT ON`, but that will not work for me as i have validation in my WCF service that depends on result of row affected from `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Related/Duplicates? [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602478/sql-server-complaining-about-triggers-returning-result-sets) [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570836/error-a-trigger-returned-a-resultset-and-or-was-running-with-set-nocount-off)

Comment: no one is answering me i dont know if my question was not clear enough ?

Comment: You have *specific* validation in your code that *requires* that the triggers fire? Do you not see that as unnecessary coupling/complexity between two parts of the system?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try putting SET NOCOUNT OFF towards the end of the trigger and see if it resolves your issue.  Also take a look at the following
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/5ee185e6-1980-4209-87f6-abeb9c5933fa/

Comment: This resolution would not be driven by understanding. It would be jiggling things around until they happen to work. I object to that. Also, the OP rightfully requests an explanation of the problem.

Comment: I see his question, The link in my post should give more insight as to why its happening.

Comment: i tried to use set nocount off at the end of the trigger but it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Please, if at all, then you need to `SET NOCOUNT ON`(!) in the **beginning** (!) of the trigger. That's because `nocount off` can lead to returning values, and this can lead to recursion problems. But as @usr writes, the problem needs more analysis. Trying randomly around should be last resort.